# force itunes to download new podcast feed

Tags: itunes, podcast

With Google news and Bing news you can "ping" the mothership and the will download the feed instantly.

Is there a programmatic way to inform itunes, that there is a new episode at my podcast feed. Usually it takes 24 hour. I know that.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way?